# I can connect via ssh but not with remote desktop

Tags: remote-desktop

I have two laptops, one with windows 10, and another with Ubuntu 18.04.1 (with gnome desktop, the default one)

On the Ubuntu laptop, I installed the ssh server and the xrdp server (enabled xrdp `sudo systemctl enable xrdp`, opened the firewall `sudo ufw allow 3389` , etc.). On the windows laptop I installed winscp.

On the windows laptop, I can use winscp to connect to the Ubuntu laptop. However the windows remote desktop application cannot connect to the Ubuntu laptop.

Any idea on why is this?
How can I fix it?

Comment: How do you specify the Ubuntu computer? Use the IP address if the computer-name does not work.

Comment: have there any error showed on connection try? (both side, linux server and windows client), have you try out with other RDP client like remmina?

Comment: Does it work within the firewall?

Comment: @harrymc: I already use the IP address

Comment: Have you done all these [configuration settings](https://www.tweaking4all.com/software/linux-software/use-xrdp-remote-access-ubuntu-14-04/)?

Comment: Those instructions were valid when ubuntu was using Unity which was not RDP compatible. Now Ubuntu uses Gnome which is RDP compatible. Apart from that, yes I did configure xrdp.

Comment: Does RDP work with ufw disabled?

Comment: Does netstat on Ubuntu show port 3389 listening? Can you telnet from Win10 to Ubuntu on port 3389?

Answer (score 3):

Log in to the Linux box, open a terminal window.and type

```
  sudo tcpdump -n -i any src or dst IP.OF.WIN.BOX
```

Then try rdp and see.if you are getting any packets from the Windows.box. If yoy see packets entering but not leaving you know the problen is in the Linux box.

Check that rdp server is listening on the correct interface by

```
  telnet ip.of.lin.box 3389
```

And seeing if you get an rdp banner. If not, you know rdp is not running, or if it is  it is not listening on the correct interface or firewalled.

Check that your system is using ufw rather then firewalld or something else. To check the underlying firewall

```
sudo iptables -vnL
```

Check input for DEST 3389 tcp and output for new/rstablished/related rule.

Comment: I was sshing and ftping with no problem, but not able to connect via RDP from remmina to Win10.
After command `sudo tcpdump -n -i any src or dst IP.OF.WIN.BOX` I connected via RDP on first attempt.
Is this something expected? I would have guessed this command is only for listening, not for enabling anything.

Comment: @sancho.s.reinstatemonicacelio Correct - that command is only listening for traffic.